# Neutraler Begriff für „Gendersprache“

Tags: single-word-request, terminology, gender-neutrality

Gibt es einen neutralen Begriff für sprachliche Konstruktionen wie den Gender-Gap oder Ähnliches?

Die Befürworter sprechen z. B. von „nicht-diskriminierender Sprache“, aber wenn man sich den Begriff zu eigen macht, dann übernimmt man deren Ansicht, dass die traditionelle Sprache diskriminierend sei.
Die Gegner verwenden Begriffe wie „Gender-Gaga“, werten damit aber die Position der Gegenseite stark herab.

Gibt es einen etablierten Begriff, mit dem das Phänomen neutral benannt werden kann?

Comment: "Gleichstellung der Geschlechter"? Oder impliziert das zu stark, dass sie nicht gleichgestellt sind?

Comment: "Sprachliche Neutralität" könnte man passend machen. Aber in diesem Bereich kann man fast überhaupt nichts sagen, ohne bei bestimmten Personengruppen anzuecken.

Comment: Ich schätze mal, "Gendersprache" ist bereits der neutralste (und etablierteste) Begriff..

Comment: Es ist nicht der Ausdruck, der nicht neutral ist, sondern der Begriff. „Gender-X“ (egal, welches Wort du für „Gender“ verwendest), soll auf eine Problematik hinweisen, und – ohne eine Bewertung vorzunehmen – einige Leute stören sich daran, andere nicht.

Comment: Gebräuchlicher ist meiner Ansicht nach "inklusive Sprache". Aber auch dieser unterstellt eben, dass das generische "er" ausgrenzend sei und nicht nur eine tote Konvention. Da darüber keine Einigkeit herrscht, dürfte es schwer sein, einen unstrittigen Meta-Begriff zu finden. Man müsste schon so etwas wie "Geschlechts-bewusste Sprechweise" konstruieren. Das herkömmliche "er" mag ausgrenzend sein oder nicht, aber jedenfalls lenkt es *nicht* die Aufmerksamkeit auf die Problematik.

Comment: Was ist mit den Begriffen, die auf https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschlechtergerechte_Sprache erwähnt sind?

Answer (score 4):

Anfang 2016 habe ich eine größere Zahl an Sprachleitfäden (überwiegend aus dem behördlichen und akademischen Umfeld Deutschlands, Österreichs und der Schweiz) für diesen Bereich gesammelt und teilweise ausgewertet. Sie enthielten u.a. diese Attribute und Phrasen im (Unter-)Titel:

- *gerecht*: *geschlechtergerecht* (mit Abstand am häufigsten verwendet), *gendergerecht*
- *sensibel*: *geschlechtersensibel*, *gendersensibel*
- *nicht-sexistisch* (eher ältere Beispiele)
- *nicht-diskriminierend* (dito)
- *inklusiv* (v.a. wo es auch um Begriffe für Minderheiten geht)
- *fair*
- *modern* (selten)
- *sprachliche Gleichbehandlung*, *sprachliche Gleichstellung*
- *Gender-Mainstreaming*
- *Sprachhandeln*

Was ich nicht oder zumindest nicht an prominenter Stelle gesehen habe, sind Formulierungen und Stichwörter wie diese:

- *gendern* (eher von Kritikern und Gegnern verwendet, insbesondere in Form von *durchgendern*), *Gendering*
- *sprachliche Inklusion*
- *bewusst*: *geschlechtsbewusst*, *geschlechterbewusst*, *genderbewusst*
- *feministisch*, *Feminismus*
- *egalistisch*
- *aufgeklärt*
- *vernünftig*
- *höflich*
- *verantwortungsvoll*
- *Respekt*, *respektvoll*
- *Anstand*, *anständig*
- *Etikette*
- *Manieren*
- *Sprachwandel*

Am etabliertesten wäre hier also **geschlechtergerechte Sprache**. Das kann ich aber nicht uneingeschränkt empfehlen. Die Varianten mit *gender-* oder *-sensibel* sind sehr ähnlich.

In der sprach- und kommunikationswissenschaftlichen Literatur wird neutral häufig von der *feministischen Sprachkritik* gesprochen, von akademischen Vertreter(inne)n derselben hingegen eher von *feministischer Linguistik* (ggf. mit großem *F*) oder seltener von *linguistischem Feminismus*. Deren – zu oft – Hypothesen und – zu selten – Erkenntnisse bilden die Grundlage für die erwähnten Leitfäden und Ratgeber, die selten den Status von Vorgaben oder Regeln erreichen. Die empfohlenen Formulierungen sind also angewandte Sprachkritik oder sprachlich gelebter Feminismus.

Unabhängig vom bevorzugen Attribut rate ich von *… Sprache* ab und empfehle stattdessen ***… Sprachgebrauch*** (fachsprachlich: *Parole*).

Man sollte aufpassen, nicht die Empfehlungen für einen allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch mit dem aktivistischem Sprachhandeln zu verwechseln. Zu letzterem zählt alles, das bewusst den Lesefluss stören soll, um so auf Benachteiligung, Ungleichbehandlung oder Vernachlässigung hinzuweisen – also insbesondere Lücke `_` und Sternchen `*`, ursprünglich auch die Binnenmajuskel `…In`. Ein Grundprinzip der meisten Leitfäden ist, dass der inklusive Sprachgebrauch gar nicht bewusst und vor allem nicht negativ auffallen soll.

Comment: Zumindest in den Kreisen der Grünen (Befürworter des Phänomens) lese ich »gendern« aber recht häufig (oder habe es häufig gelesen).